# Cannot Find Node Module on Google Cloud Server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to import a file into my node server. It works perfectly on my local version. However on my Google Cloud i keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './src/client/js/libs/utils.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
```

I have also tried the following variations:

```
var UTILS = require('src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
var UTILS = require('./src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
var UTILS = require('../src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
var UTILS = require('.././src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
var UTILS = require('../../src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
var UTILS = require(__dirname + '.././src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
```

They all yield the same error.

Here is my file structure:

```
package.json
mainServer.js
src / client / js / libs / utils.js
```

As mentioned it works fine on localhost by just doing ./src etc

EDIT: After changing the path to:

```
var UTILS = require(__dirname + '/src/client/js/libs/utils.js');
```

The error now changes to this:

```
Cannot find module '/app/src/client/js/libs/utils.js'
```

Comment: Try this: `var UTILS = require(__dirname + '/src/client/js/libs/utils.js');`

Comment: Updated the question. The error changed. I didnt create the app folder